# how to merge multiple overlapping datasets with different units of measurement

Tags: data-transformation, overlapping-data

I have many overlapping datasets of molecules and their respective binding affinities to a receptor structure. Each dataset comes from a different experimental assay and conditions, therefore the binding affinities are not directly comparable. It is like if the units of measurement of each experiment are different. To give you an example, the simple scenario is the following:

```
Assay A:
M1=-9.2
M2=-9.0
M3=-8.5
M4=-8.2
M5=-7.9

Assay B:
M6=-10.5
M2=-9.8
M7=-9.0
M8=-8.1
M4=-7.4
M9=-7.0
```

As you can see molecules M2 and M4 are common in both datasets, but their binding affinities are different. So is their ratio of binding affinities (9/8.2 versus 9.8/7.4) as well as the range of binding affinities (min and max) in both datasets. My question is, how can I find the optimum transformation of both datasets to a common reference value system in order to merge the two datasets into a super set that I will use to train an ANN? The datasets are too small (10-40 molecules) to convert the binding affinities to Z-scores and then work with them.

Comment: Is this the same receptor being used in each of the Assays, or do the Assays involve different receptors or different forms of the receptor? How many Assays and how many Molecules are involved? Can you say more about the ways in which the "experimental assays and conditions" may differ? And to what purpose will your ANN be applied?

Comment: Of course it is the same receptor. Usually I have 2 or 3 assays ranging from 10 to 40 molecules each. The different conditions may be many things, like in one assay the binding affinity was measured with fluorescence while in the other with microscale thermophoresis, the buffers may be different, the temperatures, etc. I want to use all these datasets together in order to train an ANN that will be able to predict the relative binding affinity of new molecules that bind to this receptor.

Answer (score 2):

Binding affinities can be very dependent on buffer composition and temperature, which differ among assays, and I don't know how comparable fluorescence and thermophoresis results might be, so this is a very difficult problem. The best way to proceed would be to do all the experiments under the same conditions, but presumably you are instead trying to get what you can out of data that have already been collected, perhaps from literature reports.

It would be safest to incorporate the information you have on temperatures, buffer compositions, assay readout mechanisms, etc for each assay into a model (statistical and/or theoretical) that accounts for those between-experiment differences, then use that model to take the affinity observed under each specific actual condition and transform it to a predicted affinity under a chosen standard assay condition that is uniform for all molecules. Then use that predicted affinity under the standard condition in your ANN. If there's enough overlap of the same molecules among the different conditions, and there are few enough different conditions, you might have some hope of success. (Perhaps you could even include the information about assay conditions into your ANN, but I have little experience with that type of modeling.)

If you ignore the physico-chemical differences among assay conditions, I fear that you are asking for trouble.

*In response to comments:*

What you propose in your second comment would be one type of statistical model, but it might be very dependent on the order in which you chose to do the scaling/fitting. Better might be a regression of each observed affinity against predictor variables including the molecule tested (as a categorical factor), the assay type (A,B,C, etc, again as a categorical factor), and any other relevant characteristics of the observations. This would tend to pool all available information efficiently. This would provide regression coefficients for each molecule (with assay held constant) and for each assay type (with molecule held constant). You would have to do quality control as with any regression model, in particular whether this use of molecule and assay type as separate predictors is good enough. (Your scaling/fitting proposal makes such an assumption implicitly.) Then you could choose to express the result for each molecule as its predicted affinity in one particular assay type, based on the regression model.

Under the assumptions you seem willing to make, what you want to accomplish might be done simply with a linear regression, For example, in R you could write

> `myModel <- lm(value ~ molecule + assay, data=myData)`

where `myData` has one row for each observation, with one column for the observed value, one column for the molecule code, and one column for the assay type used. That would allow adjustment for systematic shifts in values among assay types, and would provide coefficients for each of the molecules and assay types that minimize the mean square error in the observed values. You then could get predicted values for observations under any combination of molecule and assay type with

> `predict(myModel,newdata=desiredConditions)`

where `desiredConditions` has one row for for each combination of molecule and assay type, with column names as used for `myData`.

As the data seem to be log10 values of dissociation constants, it's not clear what a difference in "scale" between assays would mean, physically. If all combinations of assay and molecule were observed you could simply include an interaction between `molecule` and `assay` in your regression. Otherwise a mixed model in which different assays are allowed to have different intercepts and different slopes might work. That might sound complicated, but these are well established methods that could accomplish what you want without your having to re-invent them from scratch. As you are interested in data modeling with ANN, it probably would be wise to become well acquainted with these older but still extremely useful regression tools for data modeling and prediction.

Comment: What you suggest is impossible. I was thinking of a simpler solution. To me it seems like a problem of rescaling and fitting.

Comment: Or otherwise an objective function minimization problem, when the objective function can be the root mean square deviation between the affinities of the common molecules in the two data sets. I could work iteratively, first rescale and fit assay B to match A, then proceed to assay C and so forth.

Comment: @user1783988 see my addition to the answer. In addition to the statistical issues, make sure your approach makes sense in terms of the physical chemistry. This approach might be very dangerous if, say some molecules had titratable groups with _pK_ values near the _pH_ values of the buffers, but the buffers differed in specific _pH_ values. Then you could not simply scale/fit (in either your method or the regression method I suggest) without taking molecule/assay interactions into account.

Comment: That with the pH was a good point!

Comment: I cannot follow your rationale about regression, it seems too coplicated. It would help me if you could express it mathematically with vectors. But wouldn't be simpler to address it as an optimization problem? Essentially for each Assay I need to find two missing variables, the optimum shift Sh and the scale factor Sc. So if I have 3 Assays A, B, C lets say, I am looking for the optimum values of Sh_A, Sc_A, Sh_B, Sc_B, Sh_C, Sc_C that minimize the RMSD between the binding affinities of the overlapping molecules.

Comment: Your values seem to be logarithms of dissociation constants, so the main differences among assays are likely to be shift (differences in log dissociation constant) rather than scale; it's even hard to think about what an adjustment for "scale" among assays would mean physically with such data. Regression would find the coefficients that minimize mean-square error between the observations and the predictions based on the regression model. See addition to end of answer.

Comment: EdM I think that we describe the same solution. RMSD is the RMSE, "scale" is the slope and "shift" is the intercept in the Regression terminology. Essentially, I am searching for each dataset the optimum slope and shift that minimize the RMSE. I managed to work it out via scipy.optimize.minimize Python function. It gives you more flexibility than multivariate regression, for instance to define your own error function and apply constraints.

Comment: As for the combination of datasets, I do it at the level of binding affinities before the log transform. In the future, I would like to test it at the level of the ANN predictions which have the same range as the log transformed binding affinities (sometimes there is not enough overlap between the training sets, but there is overlap in the test set which is always the same). Btw, I don't know if you were familiar before with all these info about the raw data that I use, but I appreciate your effort to explain what is the best strategy according to my data attributes.